# capture Touch event from the panorama control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I made my own user control that captures touch events via Touch.FrameReported. When i place my control on a 'normal' page everything works fine. But when i place it in a panorama control it goes wrong, the up and down movement works as expected, but when i move my finger left or right the panorama control moves with it. How can i stop this behavior?

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your control isn't too large (say like a toggle switch) this solution posted recently seems to be working out for people for dealing with gesture conflicts on pano / pivot. You might like to check it out.

[Preventing the Pivot or Panorama controls from scrolling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2010/11/22/preventing-the-pivot-or-panorama-controls-from-scrolling.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

For UX reasons though I wouldn't consider doing this on anything larger as it's likely to cause confusion for users.

Comment: Nice one :) let us know if anything else needed to Answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You dont'!

Don't put [custom] gestures on a pivot or panorama page. You've already hit one of the technical limitations for doing so but there are bigger potential UX issues you would have to deal with.

Comment: also see the comment from eskerber on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966946/how-to-stop-the-wp7-pivot-control-handling-the-flick-gesture-event-in-silverlight/3967066#3967066 > your app may not get through marketplace acceptance if you do this