# Bing Map and Pivot

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having an issue that I'm unable to fix, I've a pivot with a bing Map in one of its screens, the thing is when you flick (scroll horizontally) on the map, the pivot transition is also performed...
Is there a solution or even a hack/workaround to avoid this side effect ?

Thanks in advance
Miloud B.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that most people are doing is not putting a live map in a pivot.

Most of the time where you do see a map in a pivot, its just a static image generated by the map control.  Then some type of interaction like a tap or something takes you to another page that hosts the live map control.

Comment: Hi John, I fixed it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888947/wp7-toggle-switch-in-a-pivot-control/4043932#4043932) Thank you

Comment: then you should add that as an answer and mark yourself correct so the question shows as answered :)