# Is a toggle switch inside a pivot item against Windows phone 7 UI guidance?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, marketplace

Anybody knows if Marketplace certifications are strict about a toggle switch inside a Pivot Item. Since the default template of a Toggle propose to flick it to change the value (but you can also tap on it!), I might think this is a problem with UI guidance.

But I can't find any official document from Microsoft that states it clearly.

Anybody knows something about this? Any link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to prevent the pivot control from reacting to the flick gesture (see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888947/wp7-toggle-switch-in-a-pivot-control)), but in most situations you can use the toggle switch without any major issues. I have a settings page as part of a pivot in one of [my apps](http://windowsphonegeek.com/AppHub/Application/d05285d5-a504-e011-9264-00237de2db9e), and it uses multiple toggle switches without any major usability issues. It has passed certification multiple times, so there is no strict rule against toggle switches on pivot pages.

Comment: Thanks Greg. My worry was about certification and was wondering if anybody got caught at certification due this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [Application Certification Requirements here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). The UI Guidelines can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Having any control that uses the same gesture as that of its parent container is generally not recommended. Despite the fact that the `toggle` control can be tapped or flicked, you don't know what the user is used to doing.

Could you not use a `Checkbox` instead? Your UI design shouldn't rely on hoping the user uses controls in one particular way (i.e. tapping instead of sliding).

Comment: Of course we can use a checkbox, but Toggle Switch would be consistent witht the rest of the app. Only at one place I have a toggle switch inside a PivotItem, and I am looking for official statement from MS against this practice.

Comment: @Mathieu Hetu - I've given the two links of where the official statements would be. If it's not in those two links, you should be free to do it. There's a hack you can do described here which will stop the pivot from scrolling if you're on the `toggle` control http://mine.tuxfamily.org/?p=111